# How to Install .NET Framework 4 on Windows 7 Bootcamp

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp

I am trying to install the Microsoft .Net Framework 4 on a Windows 7 bootcamp partition on my MacBook Pro. It always fails. I have tried installing it via the web platform installer and also the standalone download, but neither works.

This is the error message from the standalone .Net Framework Installer log:

```
Exe (C:\c6966332def2afc3e143c2e5079951\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu) failed with 0xc8000222 - (null).
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0xC8000222) (Elapsed time: 0 00:01:02).
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: You might have better luck on superuser.com or stackoverflow.com, since this doesn't seem to be "Mac" or "OS X" related. Maybe there's something on the bootcamp (permissions?) but you will find more "windows" users/developers in those other sites.

Comment: I'm leaving this here because, based on the OP's answer, it was a Mac-side virtualization issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I left out in my question that I was using VMware to access my bootcamp partition, where it didn't work. When I rebooted into "pure" bootcamped windows 7 the install went perfectly.